# What buttons are required on android device?

Tags: buttons, home-button

Typically there are three buttons on the device a back button home button and an overview button.

Which of these buttons are required by the standard or de facto standard?

Comment: Home, maybe? Lots of Chinese devices (with non-standard UX) here employ a single touch-and-press home key to achieve various functions.

Comment: @AndyYan I would agree with you accept according to this video it is tap for back press for home https://www.forbes.com/sites/bensin/2016/08/06/this-chinese-company-changed-how-one-navigates-within-android-and-i-think-its-the-future/2/#4bf15c7b2eda

Comment: Precisely. Meizu's mBack and ZUK's U-Touch are 2 wider-known examples. I don't really know how Google views those implementations, though. I'm a supporter of onscreen nav keys myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 if you don't include Hardware Reset, three are mandatory: Home, Menu and Back.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524758/are-the-4-android-buttons-standard-ex-back-button-menu-button - almost the same question, same answer.

Comment: That question is dated since they got rid of the menu button a while ago.  I think the overview button might be optional.